# Writing Date Value

Tags: c#, io, globalization

I am writing some date values in US format (MMDDYYYY) using my programme to a csv file in c#.
This is a WPF Application. If a user has different regional settings like UK in their computers the date values are flipping. how can i make sure that no matter what the users regional settings are my application will write the date values in the US format?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a small, working code sample that illustrates your problem.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5075/Culture-Invariant-DateTime-values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
Console.WriteLine(dateToDisplay.ToString("MMddyyyy"));
```

Comment: Actually setting the CurrentCulture to get culture behavior is not the best way to get this. You should just use the override that takes an IFormatProvider which CultureInfo implements. Also you probably want the InvariantCulture:
dateToDisplay.ToString("MMddyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the format when converting the date to a string (I'm not sure if that's how you are displaying the date, though):

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
string s = d.ToString("MMddyyyy");
```

For more detail on the date format string see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx